# Override service provided in NgModule in a web component

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, web-component

I have an angular library that exports its components as web components. Here's an excerpt of my `app.module.ts`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injector, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import reducers from '../store/reducers';
import { Effects } from '../store/effects';
import { DefaultPreferencesService } from '../services/preferences.service';
import { SampleComponent } from './sample-component/sample-component.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    SampleComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    EffectsModule.forRoot([Effects]),
    HttpClientModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument()
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: 'PreferencesService', useClass: DefaultPreferencesService }
  ],
  bootstrap: [],
  entryComponents: [
    SampleComponent,
  ]
})
export class SampleModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    customElements.define('lib-sample', createCustomElement(SampleComponent, { injector }));
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() { }
}
```

Everything works fine and I can use the exported component like this:
`<lib-sample sample-input="1234"></lib-sample>`

Now, I'd like to allow users to override the `PreferencesService` in `providers` when using `SampleComponent` as a web component.

I couldn't figure out a way of passing the custom service as a parameter to `<sample-component>`. One solution I can think of is using `useFactory`, instead of `useClass`, and check for a global service on `Window` object and instantiate the module and component with that custom service, if it exists. But my preference is doing it via a parameter passed directly to the web component.

Comment: Hey @kaveh, did u manage to get the proper solution?

Comment: @KalpeshPatel I can't remember the exact solution, but I don't think I found a straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Thanks for letting know abou this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a string `PreferencesService` as a token. Use an [InjectionToken](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) instance as a Token. If an user imports your `SampleModule`, and want to use another service, he only need to provide another service for the same InjectionToken in the module importing your `SampleModule`.

Comment: That's true when you're using this as an angular component, but my question is about web components.

Comment: Nope! I just quit using angular! :D